# Identify two amines

Tags: organic-chemistry, structural-formula, amines, identification

I was reading a random text about the surface chemistry of YBaCuO superconductors. In the text, there was a table. The table had a list of several chemical compounds, including these two:

- Alkyl Amine: FcC(O)NH(CH2)4NH2
- Aryl Amine: p-Fc-C6H4-NH2

Two amines. After extensive search, I was unable to find a structural formula for it (the closest I've found was [this](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/o-phenylenediamine#section=Top)). I even tried to draw all structural formulas I could think off in a piece of paper. But I couldn't draw a single one satisfying the second one (the easiest probably).

Can you identify these amines? What's their structural formula?

Comment: What is 'Fc'? Or is that part of the question?

Comment: @gilleain Its a good question. I have no idea what Fc means. I assume it most be something from coordination chemistry. In my searchs, I simply ignored the Fc- and the p-Fc-.

Comment: Fc = ferrocenyl; and *p*-Fc = *para*-ferrocenyl.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The proposed strucutre of these compound are, correct me if i am wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

$\ce{Fc}$ stands for [ferrocenyl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrocene).

So the first compound is an amide of ferrocenecarboxylic acid and tetramethylene diamine, and the second compound is p-ferrocenyl aniline.